# Crear variable condicional - Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio, formato-condicional

necesito ayuda para crear una variable condicional a otras dos. En específico, necesito identificar aquellas filas de la variable "SECCION" que presentan más de un caso en otra variable llamada "CODIGO".

Por ejemplo, tengo esta tabla:

| Sección | CODIGO |
| --- | --- |
| 1111111 | 52524 |
| 1111111 | 696615 |
| 1111111 | 52524 |
| 1551545 | 651475 |
| 32556515 | 56421 |
| 155322211 | 5641468 |
| 44552222 | 22222 |

Y necesito que crear una variable que marque todos aquellos casos en los que, la variable SECCION tenga más de un caso en la variable CODIGO (1: se cumple la condición, 0: no se cumple la condición), quedando de esta manera:

| Sección | CODIGO | CONDICIONAL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1111111 | 52524 | 1 |
| 1111111 | 696615 | 1 |
| 1111111 | 52524 | 1 |
| 1551545 | 651475 | 0 |
| 32556515 | 56421 | 1 |
| 155322211 | 5641468 | 0 |
| 32556515 | 22222 | 1 |

Muchas gracias

Comment: Hola! Recuerda que as preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para recordar cómo funciona el sitio. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Comment: Que pasaría si la sección 1111111 no tuviese el código 696615 y solo apareciera dos veces el código 52524, también la columna condicional tendría que ser 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En base al extracto que compartiste, sólo una sección cumple esta condición. Se puede lograr identificando el número de observaciones por Sección y luego asignando 1 a aquellas que tienen más de una observación, con la ayuda de tidyverse:

```
library(tidyverse)

df = data.frame(Sección = c(
  1111111,
  1111111,
  1111111,
  1551545,
  32556515,
  155322211,
  44552222),
   CODIGO = c(
  52524,
  696615,
  52524,
  651475,
  56421,
  5641468,
  22222   
   ))

df %>% group_by(Sección) %>% 
  summarise(n = n()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(CONDICIONAL = ifelse(n>1, 1, 0)) %>% 
  select(Sección, CONDICIONAL) -> cond

df %>% right_join(cond, by = 'Sección')
##     Sección  CODIGO CONDICIONAL
## 1   1111111   52524           1
## 2   1111111  696615           1
## 3   1111111   52524           1
## 4   1551545  651475           0
## 5  32556515   56421           0
## 6 155322211 5641468           0
## 7  44552222   22222           0
```

Answer (score 0):

Una solución con R base:

```
df$CONDICIOMAL <- (merge(df,
                        aggregate(. ~ Sección, df, length),
                        by="Sección",
                        suffixes = c("",".y"))[, "CODIGO.y"] > 1) * 1
```

Básicamente:

- Con `aggregate(. ~ Sección, df, length)` obtenemos un conteo de repeticiones por `Sección`
- Lo unimos junto al `df` mediante el `merge`
- Verificamos las repeticiones mayores a uno y transformamos el resultado en un número